# How can I perform a listener on one frame, not all?

Tags: actionscript-3, listener

How can I take this code:

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, char_coll);
function char_coll(ev : Event) : void {
    if(w1.hitTestObject(stand)){
        w1.gotoAndPlay(1);
        cash1 = cash1 + 1;

}
}
```

and use it only so it listens on one frame and not all frames? For example, I would like if I could specify for it to listen on frame 2. Could someone show me how this could be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, char_coll);
function char_coll(ev : Event) : void
{
    if(currentFrame==2 && w1.hitTestObject(stand))
    {
        w1.gotoAndPlay(1);
        cash1 = cash1 + 1;
    }
};
```

Rob

Comment: I did a test and I'm still receiving an error. The reason is I have another object that brings me to frame three (this is frame 2) and then it loops around and performs this function but of course I don't have the w1 movieclip on the stage, so how would I perform this so it skips this function and event listener if it's not on frame 2?

Comment: You can still do this with one if statement. Just put currentFrame==2 before w1.hitTestObject(stand). If the first condition fails (e.g., currentFrame != 2) then it won't even try the second condition.